# Julia DSP package resampling function error

Tags: julia, signal-processing, sampling, resampling

Julia's resample function in DSP package seems to throw an error at certain resampling ratios.

If I resample the columns of the following complex array there is no error

```
Num_col = 485
Test_sample = rand(Complex{Float64},35,Num_col)

t = mapslices(Array_to_Resample -> resample(Array_to_Resample,474/Num_col), Test_sample; dims=2)
```

Whereas the following code throws an error

```
Num_col = 484
Test_sample = rand(Complex{Float64},35,Num_col)

t = mapslices(Array_to_Resample -> resample(Array_to_Resample,474/Num_col), Test_sample; dims=2)


BoundsError: attempt to access 474-element Array{Complex{Float64},1} at index [475]
in top-level scope at Testscript_Wavelet.jl:90
in  at base\none
in #mapslices#109 at base\abstractarray.jl:1994
in  at Testscript_Wavelet.jl:90
in resample at DSP\0oYMW\src\Filters\stream_filt.jl:733
in resample at DSP\0oYMW\src\Filters\stream_filt.jl:728
in filt at DSP\0oYMW\src\Filters\stream_filt.jl:673
in filt! at DSP\0oYMW\src\Filters\stream_filt.jl:660
in setindex! at base\array.jl:782
```

Is this function unable to up or down sample at particular ratio's? Is there are workaround or am I using this function incorrectly?

Comment: This has already been reported: https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/issues/317